# NSUserdefault creating multiple file in Preferences folder

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7, nsuserdefaults, preferences

I am storing my application data in `NSUserDefaults` and every time I am accessing data with different `Threads`.

My application size keep increasing and it went to `GBs`.

Please look at screen shot how file is generating in `Preferences` folder.

[image]

Comment: Can you add few more details including the code it uses?

Comment: Just storing and reading NSUserDefaults not more than that..

I am working with multiple thread as well.

Comment: Use core data instead of UserDefault,It will manage every things.